# [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '$lang')"

Tags: javascript, vue.js, iview

```html
<Row>
  <i-col :span="8"><p class="item_key">{{ this.$lang.ui.m024 }}</p></i-col>
  <i-col :span="16">
    <Checkbox
      v-model="permissions"
      v-for="item in permissionsList"
      :value="item.value"
      :key="item.value"
      :name="item.name"
    >
      {{ this.$lang.ui.m024 }}
    </Checkbox>
  </i-col>
</Row>
```

for the first {{ this.$lang.ui.m024 }}, it works well in the web page, but for the {{ this.$lang.ui.m024 }} in the Checkbox, it has an error: [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '$lang')"

Comment: You don't have to use `this` in your template

Answer (score 0):

Try to put your `String` into a `<p>`-Tag like following:

```
<Checkbox
  v-model="permissions"
  v-for="item in permissionsList"
  :value="item.value"
  :key="item.value"
  :name="item.name">
  <p>{{ this.$lang.ui.m024 }}</p> 
</Checkbox>
```

and than change this in your `<style>`:

```
.checkbox input,
.checkbox p {
  display: inline-block
}
```

Hopefully this works out for you - please let me know!

Comment: thanks, but still has the same error